# major minor exception with sonar

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am running an application in jre and jdk 1.4. But when I try to analyse my code through sonar qube it shows the following exception in cmd

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/so
ner/Main (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:539)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.3)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:55)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:187)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:289)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:274)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:235)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:302)
```

I think it might be due to the jnm and jre version. But I am not sure and I don't know how to change it.

Comment: which version of sonarqube you are using?

Comment: i am using sonar 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube analyses must be run with Java 6+. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements